# Error in metric filter pattern in cloud watch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics, amazon-cloudwatch-events

Iam  trying to create the custom cloudwatch metric from the Log Groups

I am trying to create the metric pattern for the status of the email. I just need to monitor the the response in email(success/failure)

My cloudwatch logs look like below

```
 Email status : [EmailStatusResponse{farmId=3846, emailIds='xxx', response='success'}
```

So, i just need to monitor two cases

```
response='success'
response='failure'
```

Please find the below snippet for my configuration
[image]
[image]
[image]

Can anyone pls help me with the error in the filter pattern
kindly help!

[image: Please find error message below]

Answer (score 2):

Wrap this in [double quotes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html).

> Metric filter terms that include characters other than alphanumeric or underscore must be placed inside double quotes ("").

For you it would be `"response='success'"`

Comment: so in that case i should give `"response"="success"` If this wrong...can u pls give me sample @mokugo-devops

Comment: `"response='success'"`

Comment: am getting error like `Metric filter "Email Response Failure" could not be edited.
state.hasOwnProperty is not a function` Pls help me

Comment: Try creating a new metric filter

Comment: I created new one....am getting error `Metric filter "Errror Response Success" could not be created.
state.hasOwnProperty is not a function`

Comment: Where are you getting this error? Can you provide screenshots

Comment: Out of curiosity could you not just filter for the string "success" or "failure"?

Comment: can u pls guide me how to create metric filter for specific log group..Iam attaching snippet ...can u pls say is this correct place to craete snippet

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214720/discussion-between-mokugo-devops-and-kanagam-bala).